# Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IDBCursor'

Tags: typescript, indexeddb, typescript-typings

Seems that typescirpt typings doesn't know about `value` property on `IDBCursor` interface.

```
let cursor: IDBCursor;
cursor.value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IDBCursor` interface does not have a `value` property. You should use the [`IDBCursorWithValue` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursorWithValue), which inherits from `IDBCursor`.

This code compiles without error:

```
let cursor: IDBCursorWithValue;
cursor.value;
```